# Find how many of the first n elements of an Array satisfy a condition in z3

Tags: z3, z3py

I have a z3 Array:

```
x = Array('x', IntSort(), IntSort())
```

A fixed number n:

```
n = 10
```

And a filtering condition based on simple arithmetic:

```
lambda i: Or(i == 0, i > 2)
```

What I want is to know the total number of elements from index 0 to index n which satisfy this condition (something that, if this were a normal python list, would look like `len(filter(lambda i: i == 0 or i > 2, x))`.

I can't figure out how to do this in z3.  I tried

```
y == Int('y')
solver.add(y == sum([1 if Or(x[i] == 0, x[i] > 2) else 0 for i in range(0,n)]))
```

but get the following error:

```
z3.z3types.Z3Exception: Symbolic expressions cannot be cast to concrete Boolean values.
```

Is there a way to proceed?  Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It'd be best to post the exact code you tried. For one thing, the if-then-else should be coded using the [If](https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3py.html#a2340b7cde2aa8c9dc7aeaa5dfa7e851f) construct and the sum is best expressed using [Sum](https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3py.html#a5b19643b595f73c8255f9cf1b1b066c1). The following works fine, for instance:

```
from z3 import *

x = Array ('x', IntSort(), IntSort())

solver = Solver()

n = 10
y = Int('y')
solver.add(y == Sum([If(Or(x[i] == 0, x[i] > 2), 1, 0) for i in range(0,n)]))

print solver.check()
print solver.model()
```

But this'll be satisfiable for all values of `y` since there is no constraint on the contents of the array `x`.

Comment: many thanks, this gave me what I wanted (I just needed to add an additional constraint on y!)